# Scrollpane not working while using jquery fade in on div

Tags: jquery

I'm experiencing a very odd problem. I'm using jquery.scrollpane.js to get custom scrollpanes
and I would like to have a div hided when page is loading:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
$(window).load(function(){
  $(".container").fadeIn("slow");
});
</script>
```

And the HTML

```
<div class="container" style="display:none;">
```

The fade works like a charm, but then the scrollpane is not working any more..

Here's the code to initiate the scrollpane

```
<script type="text/javascript">
            $(function()
            {
                $('.scroll-pane').jScrollPane({autoReinitialise:true}); 
            });
        </script>
```

Can somebody help my out?

Comment: What scrollpane stopped working? Could you provide a little more information?

Comment: please post codees related to scrollpane too

Comment: @bipen I've edited the post with the scrollpane code!

Comment: @bipen Your solution did not work at all...it then shows nothing!

Comment: @bipen... I've got it working... see my code below!

Answer (score 0):

I've got it working now by the following code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(window).load(function(){
$(".container").fadeIn("slow");
});
$(function()
{
$('.scroll-pane').jScrollPane({autoReinitialise:true});
});
</script>
```